# Pause Exoplayer every 100 ms, resume after 500 ms

Tags: android, timertask, android-handler, exoplayer

I would like to pause video playback with Exoplayer every 100 ms, then resume playback after 500 ms. I have not found any examples.

[EDIT]
The following code does the job:

```
    final Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
  private long time = 0;
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    if (!player.getPlayWhenReady()) {time += 500; player.setPlayWhenReady(true); h.postDelayed(this, 100);}
      else {time += 100; player.setPlayWhenReady(false); h.postDelayed(this, 500);}
  }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Handlers or build a mechanism for the delays (100 and 500 ms) -
When you want to play use `player.setPlayWhenReady(true);` and `player.setPlayWhenReady(false);` for pausing.

You can also use the callback `public void onStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState)` for states changing coming when ExoPlayer out-of-the-box.